# Will packets directed to LAN devices be kept inside the network when using third party services?

Tags: lan

According to literature, packets won't leave the LAN if the destination device is in the same network. However, in an everyday's world situation where we use a lot of third party services like WhatsApp, Instagram, Telegram, Outlook, etc; does this still apply?

I suppose it would have to leave the network to get to their servers and then get redirected to the destination address, even if it's the same LAN as the sender; or is there a cache-thing that prevents this after one first connection has been made?

Would it be different with a P2P game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in an everyday's world situation where we use a lot of third party services like WhatsApp, Instagram, Telegram, Outlook, etc; does this still apply?

In that case, the destination is *outside* your network and, obviously, the data does leave your network.

Generally with those applications, clients talk to servers. A client initiates a connection, uploads or downloads some information, and then closes the connection. Another client may retrieve the former information afterwards.

Peer-to-peer means that peers communicate without an intermediate server, so usually that data won't leave your network.

Answer (score 1):

We must distinguish between the network level destination of the packet, and the final destination of the information carried by those packets. They are often not the same.

In most applications, clients do not send packets directly to each other. For example if you send an email using a traditional mail client your client sends the email to a mailserver, that mailserver will pass the email on to the recipient's mailserver (unless they happen to be the same server) and the recipient's mailserver will hold the mail until the recipient downloads it (and possibly longer).

Some applications, particularly those involving high bandwidth or desiring low latency will attempt to set up direct connections between clients. Depending on the particular network situation they may or may not succeed in doing so. If they do not succeed they will often pass the data through a central server. Whether an app chooses to pass data directly or via a central server may also depend on how the user uses the application, for example a video chat app may attempt to use direct connections for 1:1 meetings, but use a central server for meetings involving more than two people.

If you need to ensure local traffic stays local, either for legal, performance, cost, reliability or whatever other reason, you need to ensure that the servers are inside your network.